# VSCode & MacTex: clicking on a problem does not navigate to the source

Tags: errors, warnings, mactex, directory, vscode

Recently, I've just shifted from Win to Mac, but I encountered a problem on the setup of Microsoft VSCode with MacTex. After one builds a tex project, there might be warnings and errors shown in the PROBLEMS column. Please help.

In my win10, clicking on a warning should lead to the source where the problem stems from, so that I can correct my code. However, in my current Mac setup (which seems right at all other aspects), a click leads to an error message "The file is not displayed in the text editor because it is a directory." I don't know what to do so that I can have the old function back, or if there are alternatives.

Some information that may help:
let's say the main.tex file lies in the project folder named *proj*; then the directory to which I'm led is the folder *maths* which contains *proj*. Moreover, almost all the warnings shown in PROBLEMS are placed under ~/maths (as in the error message).

Comment: Problem fixed by deleting the "trusted path" of vscode.